# Dynamic number within shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I need to write a dynamic shortcode. The original says: 
[... width="940" height="200" ...]

I need to have this: 
[... width="`<php>`" height="`<php>`" ...]

How do I get this to happen??

Thanks, Floyd

Comment: Now there’s the problem. I tried to do something, that isn’t possible at all. Thanks for your answer though... I wish I had a better start in this forum. :)

Answer (score 1):

Shortcodes are plain text wrapper made exactly for cases when PHP code is not available or should not be used.

1. You can concatenate that to string and evaluate it with [`do_shortcode()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode).
2. You can look up function that powers shortcode (set up with [`add_shortcode()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode)) and use it in PHP code directly.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I made a mistake in the question. I have this: `<?php echo do_shortcode('[... width="940" height="200" ...); ?>`and I want to have this: `<?php echo do_shortcode('[... width="<javascript>" height="<javascript>" ...); ?>` I know it is strange, but probably someone will get me...

Comment: @Sgt. Floyd Pepper please edit your question with those details... And now I am even more confused about what you are trying to do. :)